# Unable to delete right to left language columns using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, collation

I'm using stored procedure to delete a row from MSSQL database based on a column that uses nvarchar(100) and Persian language. 
when i want to insert into this column,  i use the word N before the record to be able to perform the insert operation :

```
insert into materialPrice values(  N'persian word',1000,100,0,0,0,0)
```

the problem is when i want to delete the same record, stored procedure does not work :

```
create proc spRemoveMaterial
@materialName nvarchar(100)
as
begin 
delete from materialPrice where materialName = @materialName
end
```

I've tried to use N before @materialName but it returend syntax error. how could it be done ?

Comment: are you populating @materialName with N' before the literal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the database collation, following code has fixed it :

ALTER database MaterialDB COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

The `N` is a marker that causes the string literal to be represented in Unicode--implying that you are inserting into a Unicode column.

You should be able to convert the variable to Unicode with `cast`.  Something like:

```
cast(@materialName as nvarchar(100))
```

With the correct type (`nchar` or `nvarchar`) and length to match the column.